# I got a missing value error on if condition

Tags: r, function, compiler-errors, syntax-error, logic

```
    realfunction1<-function(x){
  (5*x[1]-x[2])^4+(x[1]-2)^2+x[1]-(2*x[2])+12
}
func1gradient <- function(gradient){
  x<-0
  y<-0
  x <- (20*(5*gradient[1]-gradient[2]))^3+2*(gradient[1]-2)+1
  y <- (-4*(5*gradient[1]-gradient[2]))-2
  
  gradient[1]<-x
  gradient[2]<-y
  return(gradient)
}

DFP<-function(Error,xk){
  
  k <- 0
  i <- 1
  alpha<-seq(from=-100,to=100,by=0.005)
  H0 <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
  Hk <- H0
  repeat{
    
    dk <- (-1)*(Hk%*%func1gradient(xk))
    
    if(abs(dk[1]) <= Error && abs(dk[2]) <= Error){ ####ERROR LINE
      
      return(xk)
      
    }else{
      
      for(i in i:40001){
        
        vectortofindmin<-matrix(c(1:40001),nrow=40001)
        
        variables <- xk+(alpha[i]*dk)
        
        f1valuetutucu<-matrix(c(1:40001),nrow=40001)
        
        f1valuetutucu[i] <- realfunction1(variables)
      }
      
      indexalpha<-which.min(f1valuetutucu)
      
      
      xknew <- xk + (alpha[indexalpha]*dk)
      
      pk <- xknew - xk
      
      qk <- func1gradient(xknew) - func1gradient(xk)
      
      
      ## A
      divisionval<-(t(pk)%*%qk)
      divisionmatix<-matrix(c(divisionval,divisionval,divisionval,divisionval),nrow=2)
      
      A <- (pk%*%t(pk))/divisionmatrix
      
      ###
      
      divisionval2<-t(qk)%*%Hk%*%qk
      divisionmatrix2 <- matrix(c(divisionval2,divisionval2,divisionval2,divisionval2),nrow=2)        
      B <- (Hk%*%qk)%*%t(Hk%*%qk)/divisionmatrix2
      ####
      Hknew <- Hk + A + B          
      Hk <- Hknew
      xk<-xknew
    } 
  }
}
DFP(Error=1e3,xk=matrix(c(33,12),nrow=2))
```

Here is my whole code, I tried every line of my code and it's working appropriately but I got an error on if line "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"  " if(abs(dk[1]) <= Error && abs(dk[2]) <= Error)". Can anyone help, why I got this error message? (I write Error=1e3 but I will reduce that error amount later, I am trying to reach working function:))

This code is representing the davidon-fletcher-powell method algorithm. If you have any addition or advice. I will be very appreciated.

Comment: As an advice, package pracma has a [`fletcher_powell`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.8.8/topics/fletcher-powell) function.

Comment: This code cannot work. After `## A` is an assignment that creates a variable `divisionmatix`. That should be `divisionmatrix` which is used in the following line. Accordingly I get the error *Object 'divisionmatrix' not found*. Please fix any obvious errors in the code and edit the question (if that is still required then).

Answer (score 1):

I did two things:

1. Fixed the typo that @Jan pointed out; and
2. Inserted a quick `tryCatch(...)` and `browser()` into the `repeat` loop.

   ```r
   iserr <-  tryCatch({if (abs(dk[1]) <= Error && abs(dk[2]) <= Error) 1;F;}, error=function(e) TRUE)
   if (iserr) {browser();1;}
   ```

   (before the real `if` statement)

After that, I ran your `DFP(...)` and it popped up with a debugging session. I then broke apart the `if` conditional:

```r
(abs(dk[1]) <= Error && abs(dk[2]) <= Error)
# [1] NA
```

This up-front is why you received *that* error. (And if you search SO with your error message [`[r] missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+missing%20value%20where%20TRUE%2FFALSE%20needed), you'll see that your exact error is discussed in many questions.)

But you need to know why that conditional is not a real true/false, so we can look at some of the dependent variables. All of the following would alarm me in one form or another (though perhaps `xk` is okay?):

```r
dk
#      [,1]
# [1,]  NaN
# [2,]  NaN
xk
#               [,1]
# [1,]  4.16513e+145
# [2,] -5.07341e+115
func1gradient(xk)
#                [,1]
# [1,]            Inf
# [2,] -8.330259e+146
Hk
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  NaN  NaN
# [2,]  NaN  NaN
```

I'm not going to disect *why* each of those allegedly numeric variables are holding unexpected values, as that would require a bit of domain-knowledge on whatever you're doing here. It might be that you find the `Inf` not completely *un*expected, but I expect that the `NaN` is surprising to you.

Go through your logic and code to find what is going wrong with each of those.

When playing with new math in functions, I often include some `if` statements that either stop prematurely or put me into a `browser()` debugging session. For instance,

```r
if (any(is.null(z), is.nan(z), is.na(z))) { browser(); 1; }
```

might be a good thing for you to check on various components before you do things that can turn zeroes, very-positive, very low, or very-negative numbers into non-numbers. (The `browser();1;` is a little bit of a hack to work around some nuances of debugging in R.)

A slightly different tact might be something like:

```r
if (!isTRUE(is.finite(z))) { browser(); 1; }
```

which should start a debugging session a little more aggressively.

You should target avoiding this type of code (e.g., `browser()`) in *production*, but while developing new R-based stuff and/or learning the nuances of R, it can save you many hours.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will try solve the error by your comments:)